# Scraping data from a container

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to scraping and would like to scrape this the "Historical Data" table from this url: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/

I have tried to use bs4 but nothing seems to work for me as it just returns an empty list...
As far as I understand, what I need to do is to find all "tr" in the container - or what?
I don't have that much code, but I think it make sense to show it to you so there is something to work with:

My code:

```
page = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are looking for is added to the page via XHR/Fetch call. You can get it like the below

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/historical?id=1&convertId=2781&timeStart=1633910400&timeEnd=1639180800')
if r.status_code == 200:
  print(r.json())
```

Comment: Do you have a way to get the JSON output into a pandas df?

Comment: There is a way to get the json into pandas. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.json.read_json.html . Note that this is a totally different question

Comment: How is it specified in that url that its Bitcoin it gets data from?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @balderman's answer, you can try this to correctly get it into an a pandas dataframe format:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/historical?id=1&convertId=2781&timeStart=1633910400&timeEnd=1639180800').json()['data']['quotes'])
```

Returning

```
                    timeOpen  ...                                              quote
0   2021-10-11T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 54734.124840616, 'high': 57793.039249...
1   2021-10-12T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 57526.8320114193, 'high': 57627.87860...
2   2021-10-13T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 56038.2567881108, 'high': 57688.66010...
3   2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 57372.8320788954, 'high': 58478.73549...
4   2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 57345.9019791856, 'high': 62757.12970...
..                       ...  ...                                                ...
56  2021-12-06T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 49413.4790992129, 'high': 50929.51909...
57  2021-12-07T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 50581.8300495181, 'high': 51934.78189...
58  2021-12-08T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 50667.6476830609, 'high': 51171.37531...
59  2021-12-09T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 50450.0820524109, 'high': 50797.16544...
60  2021-12-10T00:00:00.000Z  ...  {'open': 47642.1435531841, 'high': 50015.25298...
```

Finally using a `join()` operation we can unned the `quote` column which contains a dict with the values:

```
output = output.join(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([x]) for x in output['quote']]).reset_index(drop=True)).drop(columns='quote')
```

To obtain it in a nice and clear format:

```
                    timeOpen                   timeClose                   timeHigh                      timeLow            open            high            low            close          volume       marketCap    timestamp
0   2021-10-11T00:00:00.000Z    2021-10-11T23:59:59.999Z    2021-10-11T19:47:02.000Z    2021-10-11T00:04:02.000Z    54734.124841    57793.039249    54519.765520    57484.789465    4.263733e+10    1.083079e+12    2021-10-11T23:59:59.999Z
1   2021-10-12T00:00:00.000Z    2021-10-12T23:59:59.999Z    2021-10-12T06:14:02.000Z    2021-10-12T20:09:02.000Z    57526.832011    57627.878602    54477.974468    56041.056838    4.108376e+10    1.055926e+12    2021-10-12T23:59:59.999Z
2   2021-10-13T00:00:00.000Z    2021-10-13T23:59:59.999Z    2021-10-13T21:43:02.000Z    2021-10-13T09:10:02.000Z    56038.256788    57688.660104    54370.973228    57401.097527    4.168425e+10    1.081612e+12    2021-10-13T23:59:59.999Z
3   2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z    2021-10-14T23:59:59.999Z    2021-10-14T02:27:02.000Z    2021-10-14T18:30:02.000Z    57372.832079    58478.735499    56957.076136    57321.525280    3.661579e+10    1.080160e+12    2021-10-14T23:59:59.999Z
4   2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z    2021-10-15T23:59:59.999Z    2021-10-15T20:28:02.000Z    2021-10-15T01:20:02.000Z    57345.901979    62757.129703    56868.142693    61593.950061    5.178008e+10    1.160726e+12    2021-10-15T23:59:59.999Z
```

Comment: Cool - thanks! It seems to be a bit tricky to get the data out in a way the looks similar to the one on the website - i'll keep on trying :)

Comment: Hopefully the last edit will get you what you need ;)

Comment: That's super cool! Ty! I'll dive into the code to understand what actually happens! :D

Comment: Happy to be of help if you have a follow up question, feel free to let me know!

Comment: If you have time, it would be nice if you would try to describe exactly how the scripting code works, and how it differes from what I tried. Especially the new URL we use, how do you generate that?

Comment: Sure, in a few lines many websites have APIs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) you can use to easily access and retrieve data. The link that was used is not the front page of the website, but rather the API coinbase has and suggests using for accessing this kind of data. You should search "coinbase API" to find more about it

Comment: Okay makes sense - again thanks!

Comment: Can I ask, what would you do if you would scrape data from same website but for another crypto? Im curious how the url/api would look like