# Scraping from Coinmarketcap.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, coinmarketcap

I have previously posted a question regarding scraping of the website coinmarketcap.com ([Scraping data from a container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70315664/14435630)) which is now solved. But I still have a question about how to find/change the API url depending on the crypto currency I want to scrape from. In the question linked above this one is used to get Bitcoin:

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/historical?id=1&convertId=2781&timeStart=1633910400&timeEnd=1639180800

My question is, what should I do to get another crypto like ethereum?

I'm new to scraping and not very familiar with the terminology

Edit: To you who dislikes this, can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check their [documentation website](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/)
If you search around a bit you can find the [historical listings](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsHistorical) subpage , and on that subpage it describes the API, and you can find that there is a query called `convert_id` which translate to different fiat and crypto currency.

Nonetheless, this question should rather be asked on coinmarketcap forums or channels rather than StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you, great help! I have been looking at the documentation, but have clearly overlooked that. Was not aware of coinmarketcap having a seperate forum.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about another coin you need to specify its ID. ID you can find out:

- Via API, in the section [CoinMarketCap ID Map](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyMap) (returns data about
  all coins, pagination is required otherwise it will return only the first 5000 coins)
- In the HTML source code of the coin page, for example, the link to
  the big coin logo always contains its ID:
  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/200x200/1027.png